# Regex for multiple delimeter

Tags: java, regex, csv, parsing, logging

I have log file. I need to parse it. Between 4 and 5 column(SETv5.CacheDB and Remove 4...) "tab", in other cases a space.
If i use "\s+", then the last column is divided by spaces. How can I avoid this?

From:

17.11.2014 03:00:00.832 DEBUG: SETv5.CacheDB    Remove 4 old discounts (before Sat Nov 15 00:00:00)

To:

"17.11.2014","03:00:00.832","DEBUG:","SETv5.CacheDB","Remove 4 old discounts (before Sat Nov 15 00:00:00)"

Comment: Split with `"\t"` and then split the first chunk with `\s+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest is to use `String.split()` with a limit, to prevent the pattern from being applied more than you want.

`String[] columns = logString.split( "\\s+", 5 );`

Comment: I forgot about the limit. This is what I need. Thanks!